# Seeking QGIS equivalent to ArcMap Editor Menu Clip?

Tags: qgis, editing, clip

In ArcMap I can start an edit session, drop down the editor menu and choose "Clip" then decide whether to preserve or discard the area(s) in any other displayed layer that intersect with the clipping layer

Is there a QGIS equivalent for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it is a bit different but also very comfortable and easy. You have to open the processing toolbox and then choose "Edit feature in place". Then you have the tools to edit features depending on their type (point/line/polygon) like in ArcGis...but even more and better!

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to choose to preserve or discard the overlapping area? I only seem to get it preserving when I want that part removed and the non-overlap left

Comment: Ah... the Difference instead of Clip does that.